# Macros in C language

Tags: c, macros, printf, c99

I am using this macro with gnu99 today but I want to change this macro to support -c99 according to my project requirements

```
 #define STR(format, ...) ({static char str[256]; (void)snprintf(str, 256, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); str;})
```

I can convert the above macro to something like below but I dont know how to do with str in the end.

```
 #define STR(format, ...)                        
  do                                                                                                                         
    {                                                                                                                          
      static char str[256];                                                                    
      (void)snprintf(str, 256, format, ## __VA_ARGS__);                

    } while(0)
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: If you want to return a value from a C99 macro, you can't use the `do { ... } while (0)` construct.

Comment: You need to convert this to a varargs function.

Comment: first of all, why you want to achieve this using macro? it's absolutely a function semantics.

Comment: I would try to answer your question if I only understood what you meant by "how to do with `str` in the end".

Comment: @barakmanos: The macro should be an expression, namely the formatted string. In the GNU expression syntax, that is done with `({...; str;})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking far too complicated, just make it a single expression, and define the buffer once outside:

```
#define STR_USE static char str[256]
#define STR(format, ...) (snprintf(str, sizeof str, format, ## __VA_ARGS__), str)
```

Use `STR_USE;` in any scope you might want to call `STR` in, and use `STR` as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an implementation of `sprintf` that returns a string (instead of the character count), don't use a macro. Write a short function with a cyclic buffer of short strings instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MAX_FMT 8

char *fmt(const char *format, ...)
{
    static char buf[MAX_FMT][256];
    static int nbuf;    
    va_list va;

    nbuf++;
    if (nbuf == MAX_FMT) nbuf = 0;

    va_start(va, format);
    vsnprintf(buf[nbuf], 256, format, va);
    va_end(va);

    return buf[nbuf];
}

int main()
{
    printf("%40s\n%40s\n%40s\n",
        fmt("%s: %d°C", "Copenhagen", 7),
        fmt("%s: %d°C", "Paris", 10),
        fmt("%s: %d°C", "Athens", 16));

    return 0;
}
```

You need the functions of `<stdarg.h>` here to implement your own `printf`-like function. `vsnprintf` is like `snprintf`, except that it takes a `va_list`.

A cyclic buffer of 8 `static` char buffers allows you to return a string without allocation. You can, of course, use at most 8 calls of `fmt` at a time, e.g. inside one `printf` call.